# Opera Mobiles css3 rendering problems

Tags: opera, css, opera-mobile

when testing my website using Opera Mobile, I discovered some serious problems which I've no idea why they happen and how to fix them.

Here's a comparison between FF (Windows) and Opera Mobile (FF renders as expected):
[image]

[Here's the jsfiddle with the source](http://jsfiddle.net/Gezwm/)

Here are the differences:

1. 1st image looks weird.
2. 4th image disappeared.
3. Images has partially/missing `border-radius`.
4. `box-shadow` is missing.

I'm pretty sure that the `box-shadow` and `border-radius` are the main cause for the problems, because when removing them everything looks fine.

I would like to know why it occur and how to fix it....

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are removing `opacity` does it work better? It seems there is a very unfortunate bug mixing box-shadow and opacity. And it is tracked by CORE-39908 at Opera. I will add your example jsfiddle example to the bug report.

Comment: Yes, removing the opacity fixes the problem! There's no way I can fix it with the opacity?

Comment: Than the only solution is to remove the opacity or the box-shadow?

Comment: Edit: opacity alone cause the problem. there's no connection between this to the box-shadow.

Comment: I solved it by separating the opacity to another layer - inline div with absolute position and 100% size - solved my opera problem but still using all the CSS properties that I wanted.